# C# Generics and Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, generics

Is it possible to pass a generic type T into an instance of a winform so T is usable throughout the form?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, A Form is like any other class. You will have to modify the designer-generated code a little, and watch out that that  does not get rolled back.

```
  // TestForm.cs
  public partial class TestForm<T> : Form

 // TestForm.Designer.cs
 partial class TestForm<T>
```

Comment: Note that generic forms can't be displayed in the Form Designer, though their dscendants can.

Comment: @wrar, I was testing with VS2010 and that has no (obvious) problems with my TestForm. But I expect it to be a little feeble.

Comment: I am in the process of testing it out and will let you know how it works.

Comment: A derived, concrete form won't be designable.

Comment: Neither will a Derived generic Form.

Comment: I Added new file partial class TestForm{} its work, designer opened.

Answer (score 6):

As suggested, this can be done - but in many cases you'll find yourself fighting the framework etc. IMO it may be simpler to just pass a `Type` into the form (as a property, perhaps), and instances via an `object` property (or an interface / base-class if such applies).

You *can* use generics, but in many cases in this scenario it won't actually help you much, and the designer hates it.

Comment: Marc, the VS2010 designer doesn't seem to have any problem with a Generic Form. It fails totally with Form-inheritance though.

Comment: I know it is 12 years after this answer, but was just wondering whether what OP is asking is possible now. I have a form that performs searches on many lists of custom classes, but for it to work I have to convert each list to a DataTable for a datagrid's datasource. For larger lists the conversion is slightly slower. Is there an alternative? I am unable to make generics work in this case.

Comment: @BensonO. winforms hasn't changed much in that time; so: no, not really